# How can you track the requests your network sends to google?

Tags: google-search, search

I get an "Unusual traffic from your computer network" error when loading a Google search page in my browser (eg opening google.com), even after checking for malware on every machine on my network, checking extensions etc. The pattern in which the "Unusual" error appears is inconsistent, so i would like to know if I can track those requests or traffic Google cares about to find the culprit. Is there a software or a Windows command that does it?

Google provides [some information about it here](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640), but it's not clear what caused the issue.

Comment: What is generating the error message?

Comment: @moab I have no idea. All I know is that Google blocks you if you generate too many requests at a given period of time because they think you are a bot. I want to know how to track those requests to find the culprit.

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68858/google-unusual-traffic-from-your-computer-network